# my SSD is extremely slow, how to recover as much data as possible?

Tags: ssd

It worked fine, until one day I filled it to almost full. Now trying to copy files back from it results in very long delays. It looks like this:

1. some files are copied at respectable speed
2. some files hang the process for about 5 minutes, so hard that i can't even close the window and even other programs start to lag
3. repeat

I deleted about 30% of files from disk when I noticed it, but it didn't do much. I still can view folders and delete files, but actually reading them doesn't help.

Comment: What's your operating system? Do you know the SSD model? Have you emptied the trash?

Comment: @gronostaj windows 10, i probably need to unscrew it for that, and yes.

Comment: model is Goldfir 240GB

Comment: Goldfir SSDs have a very dubious reputation. They are extremely cheap, but the quality leaves a lot to be desired. I've heard multiple people complain that these don't handle "trim" properly and your symptoms are a classic case of that same problem. And there is no real solution for that, except buying another SSD...

Comment: @Tonny you can work around it, you just have to make sure your drive stays above 25% of free space.

Comment: @LPChip I know that, but it sounds as if the poster is beyond that point. Best you can do in that case is to shrink the partition (if possible) by 10 to 20% and hope that gradually the drive will regain speed. Which may take weeks/months depending on usage patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a known side effect of how SSD's work. You can research this by googling for `SSD TRIM` and learn how and why this is important.

Long story short, SSD's need sufficient free space for the TRIM function to be effective, which rearranges files and prevents fragmentation.

Most modern SSD's have extra free space that you cannot access in order to protect against fragmentation, but yours appears to not have this.

In order to recover your SSD and get it back up to speed, you need to find a place to store the entire content of the SSD. Copy the files off the SSD to your backup storage area and ensure that all data is good. I recommend a program such as TeraCopy, which can verify the copy once all files are copied. This is important because if something seems wrong with the destination, this is where you find out. TeraCopy can also resume the copy by skipping all on a next copy.

Once you have the files copied to the backup location, perform a quick format on the SSD.

If this SSD is the one Windows is running on too (as in, its the only device in your pc, you will have to perform the following steps from another computer, including the format.

Once the SSD is empty perform a TRIM command on your SSD to ensure that it reallocate all empty space as empty and effectively defragmentates your SSD. If your SSD is good enough, this step is likely not necessary, but better safe than sorry.

Open Powershell as Administrator and perform the following command:

```
Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter D -ReTrim -Verbose
```

where D is the driveletter the SSD got in the new computer.

Comment: But that's the whole issue, I can't copy files from SSD, it's very very slow for half of them. There are no windows on it.

Comment: Its slow, but its doable.... and it is your only option really.

Comment: You can try to trim the disk as it is now, using that command (or another way depending on the OS you use and see if the situation improves somewhat, but the answer is the recommended way to proceed here.

Comment: Also: if these files are of any importance to you, you should have backups.

Comment: How to format disk now? I tried to clear free space with ccleaner, now disk isn't visible and I can't create a partition on it. Diskpart throws error on `create partition primary`, `DiskPart has encountered an error: A device which does not exist was specified.` , and `VDS fails to write boot code on a disk during clean operation, error 800701B1@02070008`

Comment: @woopwoop399 it might actually be possible that your SSD died. A really slow SSD can also be due to it dying.

Comment: After not doing anything for 6 hours SSD ressurrected. I'm giving up on restoring any data, I formatted SSD, but running that powershell command gives me this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBYjE.png . I tried to specify drive letter with : end without : at the end, error is slightly different.

Comment: See here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/optimize-volume?view=win10-ps

Comment: You can run `Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter c -Analyze -Verbose` to see if you really need to trim the drive after the format. Maybe the drive is smart enough to have marked the cells as empty already.